# How can I use sed to extract lines between two patterns and do post processing on it in a loop?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to do something like this. Say I have the text below:

```
Start-pattern  
orange  
apple  
grape  
orange  
orange  
End-pattern  
#######  
bla bla bla  
########  
Start-pattern  
orange  
apple  
grape  
apple  
orange  
End-pattern  
#######
bla bla bla
########
Start-pattern  
orange  
orange  
orange  
End-pattern  
#######  
bla bla bla  
########
```

Here I want to print how many oranges,apples and grapes are there in between each of `Start-pattern` and `End-pattern`.

In the above example, we have 3 "orange", 1 "apple" and 1 "grape" in between 1st Start-pattern and end-pattern. 2 "orange", 2 "apple" and 1 "grape" in 2nd SP and EP and so on.

Waiting for your valuable answers.

Comment: can you add complete expected output to the question for clarity?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^Start-pattern$/{p=1;next} $1 ~ /^End-pattern$/{p=0; for (var in a) {print var,a[var];a[var]=""}; print "######"; next} p{a[$1]++}' file
```

More readable `awk`:

```
$1 ~ /^Start-pattern$/ {
    p=1;
    next
}
$1 ~ /^End-pattern$/ {
    p=0;
    for (var in a) {
        print var,a[var];
        a[var]=""
    }
    print "######";
    next
} 
p {
    a[$1]++;
}
```

**Explanation:**

We can split this `awk` as 3 blocks of code.

1. Check for `Start-pattern` pattern, then enable `p=1`.
2. Check for `End-pattern` pattern, then disable `p=0`. Then, print `a[]` with corresponding count.
3. This will store the number of occurrences of each item between these two patterns in an associative array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this out. Can you please explain how it works ? It will be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed, echo, sort and uniq):

```
sed -nr '/Start/,/End/!b;/Start/h;//!H;/End/!b;x;s/^[^\n]*\n(.*)\n.*/echo "\1"|sort|uniq -c/e;s/\n//g;p' file
```

Turn on seds grep like nature with `-n`. Store lines between `Start` and `End` in the hold space (HS) and on encountering the `End` string, replace the pattern space (PS) from the HS. Remove the start and end header/footers and using the evaluate flag of the substitution command; echo the enclosed lines into a sort and then count the unique lines using the uniq command. Remove any newlines and print the contents of the PS.